# How to join SQL tables and include missing rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Tables**

Suppose you have a table, `meal_types`, as follows:

```
meal_type_id  |  type
--------------|------------
     1        |  breakfast
     2        |  lunch
     3        |  dinner
```

The second table is called `meals`:

```
meal_id  |  food    |  meal_type_id
---------|----------|------
   1     |  bacon   |   1
   2     |  eggs    |   1
   3     |  fries   |   2
   4     |  burger  |   2
   5     |  soup    |   3
```

The third table is called `meal_counts`:

```
external_id | count | meal_id
------------|-------|---------
    1       |  100  |   3
    2       |  50   |   5
    2       |  25   |   3
    3       |  15   |   2
```

**Expected output**

Return the total counts per external_id grouped by meal_type_id. All meal_type_id values must appear for every external_id. If an external_id does not contain a meal_type_id its count must be set to 0.

```
 external_id | count | meal_type_id
 ------------|-------|-------------
     1       |  0    |   1
     1       |  100  |   2
     1       |  0    |   3
     2       |  0    |   1
     2       |  25   |   2
     2       |  50   |   3
     3       |  15   |   1
     3       |  0    |   2
     3       |  0    |   3
```

Please note that even though for external_id = 1 there are no counts for meals of type breakfast(1) and lunch(2), they are still added to the result and their count is set to 0.

**My work on this**

```
SELECT external_id, SUM(count) as total, meal_type_id
FROM meal_counts
INNER JOIN meals ON meal_counts.meal_id = meals.meal_id
INNER JOIN meal_types ON meal_types.meal_type_id = meals.meal_type_id
GROUP BY external_id, meal_type_id
```

The issue with this approach is that if an external_id does not contain a meal_type_id, it will *not* return *all* meal_types.

How can I solve this with one query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cross join, which gives you all possible combination of meal_type in meal_counts table:

```
select 
   external_id 
  ,mt.meal_type_id 
  ,coalesce(max(counter) filter (where mt.meal_type_id = m.meal_type_id),0) counter
from meal_counts mc
join meals m
  on m.meal_id = mc.meal_id
cross join meal_types mt 
group by external_id, mt.meal_type_id
order by external_id, mt.meal_type_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If  I understand this correctly, you can use a derived table getting the `external_id`s, cross join it with the `meal_types`, left join it with the `meal_counts` and use `coalesce()` to get the `count` of `0` where no join partner providing the `count` was found.

```
SELECT mc2.external_id,
       coalesce(mc3.count, 0) count,
       mt1.meal_type_id
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    mc1.external_id
                    FROM meal_counts mc1) mc2
            CROSS JOIN meal_types mt1
            LEFT JOIN meal_counts mc3
                      ON mc3.external_id = mc2.external_id;
```